# Windows : How to protect process from getting killed in C/C++

Tags: windows, c++, dll, c

Is there any "GODLY" method through which i can protect my process from getting killed
either from:
1>Task manager
2>Command prompt -- forcefully kill

Things i tried :
1. Hooking Open Process and Terminate Process

Result i got:
i could only protect it from task manager
 but it gets killed through command prompt task kill command

Comment: I think you'd benefit more asking on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Relevant [Old New Thing post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx) and a [followup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First reaction: If your process is running on your machine, you could simply choose to not terminate it.  If it's running on my machine, then it isn't your process, it's mine... and I will terminate it if I want to.

The actual answer: Ultimately, no, there isn't.

You can make it less easy by creating your process with a security descriptor that denies "Terminate" access to the Everyone group.

However an admin can always take ownership of the process, then change the SD to give themselves terminate access, and terminate it. (Unless admins on the system lack, for some reason, the "take ownership of any object" privilege.)

Comment: I dont think so jamie u cant kill mcafee exe with admin privilege. same thing i want to achieve

Comment: with hooking u can bypass kill command (not actually bypass). From task manager my exe will not get killed whoever tries to kill it may it be an admin or normal user

Comment: Yes, you can kill mcaffee.exe... but just trying to kill it while you're an admin isn't enough. And any hook can be unhooked...